# How to set default values for foreign keys in Entity Framework code-first models

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5, code-first.

I have a POCO that looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

  public Order()
  {
    this.Status = new Status() { Id = 1 }
  }
}
```

This is mapped fluently like:

```
public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
  public OrderMap()
  {
    ToTable("Order");
    HasKey(x => x.Id);

    Property(x => x.Id);
    Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

    HasRequired(x => x.Status)
      .WithMany(x => x.Orders)
      .Map(x => x.MapKey("StatusId"));
  }
}
```

In the database, the `Order` table has the default value of `StatusId` set to `1`.

However, when adding a new `Order`, I get this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Status_PK'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Status'. The duplicate key value is (1)

If I remove the assignment to `Status` in the `Order` ctor, then I get this instead:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StatusId', table
>   'MyDatabase.dbo.Order'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

How can I set default values for foreign key properties?

Answer (score 0):

Provide default status to order via constructor (otherwise new status will be inserted, because whole graph will be in *Added* state):

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    public Order(Status initialtStatus)
    {
        Status = initialtStatus;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var status = db.Statuses.Find(1);
var order = new Order (status) { Name = "Lazy" };
db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE: Another option is attaching default status entity to context or setting it's state manually:

```
var order = new Order { Name = "Lazy" };
db.Entry(order.Status).State = EntityState.Unchanged; // avoid inserting
db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: A new status isn't being inserted in the sample I provided. If at all possible, I'd also rather not have to use the data context when instantiating new Order objects to supply a Status... it just feels wrong. It's also a PITA to have code to supply it in the ctor every time (I didn't mention that almost every POCO in the application will need to do this with Status!)

Comment: @Cocowalla actually it should be inserted. If you will check state of entries in change tracker, Status will have same state as order - it will be `Added`. Thus insertion query will be generated for status

Comment: But I just get `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StatusId', table 'MyDatabase.dbo.Status'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails`

Comment: @Cocowalla just verified - with code you provided I don't have this exception. Anyway - I added another option to avoid inserting status. Also you can use `StatusId` property instead of `Status` entity (but I think it's not best solution)

Comment: I'd rather not 'pollute' the models by adding foreign key properties like StatusId that only exist for the database

Comment: @Cocowalla that's why I wrote *'I think it's not best solution'*

Comment: I know... just saying :)

Comment: Ah, it was a mapping issue with Status table which was causing it not to try to insert... had to set `.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` on the key property. So yes, now it does throw when I try the sample in my question